# How to build ffmpeg with hardware decoding support for raspberry pi? (cross compilation if possible)

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to build `ffmpeg` with decoding support for Raspberry Pi? I've read that `mmal` can do hardware accelerated decoding on the Raspberry Pi.

I've tried on debian 10 x86_64:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=${BUILD_DIR}/desktop/${FFMPEG_ARCH_FLAG} \
    --disable-doc \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --cross-prefix=${CROSS_PREFIX} \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=${FFMPEG_ARCH_FLAG} \
    --extra-cflags="-O3 -fPIC $EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
    --enable-mmal \
    --enable-omx \
    --enable-omx-rpi \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-debug \
    --disable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --disable-programs \
    --disable-muxers \
    --disable-encoders \
    --disable-bsfs \
    --disable-pthreads \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-postproc
```

where `CROSS_PREFIX=aarch64-linux-gnu-` and `FFMPEG_ARCH_FLAG=aarch64` but obviously I get `ERROR: mmal not found`. I couldn't find MMAL to compile and install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible. You can use [this](https://gist.github.com/wildrun0/86a890585857a36c90110cee275c45fd#file-compile-ffmpeg-sh) build script, which you will need to run on the Raspberry Pi itself. The part you probably care most about is towards the end:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git ~/FFmpeg \
  && cd ~/FFmpeg \
  && ./configure \
    --extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/include" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib" \
    --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm -latomic" \
    --arch=armel \
    --enable-gmp \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-libaom \
    --enable-libass \
    --enable-libdav1d \
    --enable-libfdk-aac \
    --enable-libfreetype \
    --enable-libkvazaar \
    --enable-libmp3lame \
    --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
    --enable-libopencore-amrwb \
    --enable-libopus \
    --enable-librtmp \
    --enable-libsnappy \
    --enable-libsoxr \
    --enable-libssh \
    --enable-libvorbis \
    --enable-libvpx \
    --enable-libzimg \
    --enable-libwebp \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-libx265 \
    --enable-libxml2 \
    --enable-mmal \
    --enable-nonfree \
    --enable-omx \
    --enable-omx-rpi \
    --enable-version3 \
    --target-os=linux \
    --enable-pthreads \
    --enable-openssl \
    --enable-hardcoded-tables \
  && make -j$(nproc) \
  && sudo make install
```

Note this caveat from [RaspberryPi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md):

> MMAL is a Broadcom-specific API used only on VideoCore 4 systems

This makes me think the chances of cross-compiling are low, but you can always give it a shot with this script.

Answer (score 0):

To build ffmpeg with mmal support you need to install the [raspberry userland](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland) which provides the mmal interface. Note that mmal is not supported on 64bit userland systems (See https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues/688)